# what specific applications will use this sorting scenario

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I have the following sorting scenario:

Given an input array containing unsorted data: 1, 5, 2, 6, 9

a) sort them in descending order, which is 9, 6, 5, 2, 1

b) send the maximum value 9 of current sorted list to the output

c) modify some of the rest values, i.e. 5 becomes 10, 1 becomes 3

d) update the rest of sorted list to 10, 6, 3, 2

e) repeate from b) untill all the unvisited value are sent to the output(these values might be uptated after each sent)

Does anyone know what kind of application or specific problem could use this scenario? Is the best algorithm being the use of two linked lists to swap the index instead of insert and remove large amount of updated data? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This sounds some kind of priority queue. Highest priority at a given time gets processed and thereby removed from the queue. Other elements might get a priority change and therefore move back an forth in the queue.

Assuming the list is large (so it's worth to even think about the performance) and number of updated elements is rather small compared to the total number of elements, I'd suggest to use a quicksort with all the unchanged elements considered sorted and the changed elements inserted as prescribed by the algorithm.

Independent from the algorithm if the elements are relevant in size and not just numbers you probably want to sort references or pointers to them and not the actual elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use priority queue with additional operation: key modification.
It could be used in implementation of [Dijkstra algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm).
Such data structure with underlying binary heap is described, for example, in Robert Sedgewick book 'Algorithms in C++/C/Java'

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called `Heap` (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)), which has its implementation in C++/STL as `priority_queue` and also there are functions `push_heap`, `pop_heap` (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/push_heap/) which work on array.

When using heap complexity of insertion/deletion/update is **O(logN)**, and getting maximum element is **O(1)** so it fits best to your needs.